# В Xcode 8.1 Playground не работают брейкпоинты

Tags: xcode, swift, отладка, breakpoint

Написал код в Playground:

```
import Foundation

/*
 * Игра
 * Необходимо реализовать игру «Камень-ножница-бумага».
 * Нужно дать пользователю сыграть против компьютера.
 * Камень побеждает ножницы, ножницы побеждают бумагу, а бумага побеждает камень.
*/

func rockPaperScissors() -> Any? {
  print("Welcome to game 'Rock-Paper-Scissors!'\n")
  //print("Do u want to play an one part?")
  //print("Press 'y' to play or 'n' to cancel")
  //print("***")

  //let userResponceAboutGame = readLine()

  print("Choose your item for fight!")
  print("1: Rock")
  print("2: Paper")
  print("3: Scissors")

  let userResponseAboutItem = Int(readLine()!)
  var userItem: String?

  switch userResponseAboutItem! {
  case 1:
    userItem = "Rock"
  case 2:
    userItem = "Paper"
  case 3:
    userItem = "Scissors"
  default:
    return nil
  }

  let random = Float(arc4random() / UInt32.max)
  var computerItem: String?

  if random < 0.33 {
    computerItem = "Rock"
  } else if random == 0.33 && random < 0.66 {
    computerItem = "Paper"
  } else {
    computerItem = "Scissors"
  }

  print("User's choice: \(userItem)")
  print("FIGHT!")
  print("\(userItem) VS ...")
  print("\(userItem) VS \(computerItem)")

  if userItem == computerItem {
    print("Standoff!")
  }

  if userItem == "Rock" {
    if computerItem == "Paper" {
      print("Computer win!")
    } else if computerItem == "Scissors" {
      print("You win!")
    }
  }

  if userItem == "Paper" {
    if computerItem == "Rock" {
      print("You win!")
    } else if computerItem == "Scissors" {
      print("Computer win!")
    }
  }

  if userItem == "Scissors" {
    if computerItem == "Rock" {
      print("Computer win!")
    } else if computerItem == "Paper" {
      print("You win!")
    }
  }

  return nil
}

rockPaperScissors()
```

Вызвало фатальную ошибку в консоле:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Очевидно же, что какая-то опциональная переменная не получает значение. И скорее всего проблема в переменной `userResponseAboutItem`, потому что функция `readline()` работает не так, как я ожидаю.

**Всё же, как поставить брейкпоинт в новом Xcode?**

Пробовал:

1. Выбрав строку кода, нажать комбинацию клавиш «cmd + \»;
2. Кликнуть по номеру строки кода.

**P.S.** В предыдущих версиях Xcode брейкпоинты вроде ставил без проблем. Только учусь деббагингу. Версия Xcode 8.1 (8B62)

**UPD:** `readline()` не работает в Playground, но это не отменяет вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В плейграунде нет дебаггера и нет брейкпоинтов.

Касательно вашей ошибки, насколько я понимаю readline() в плейграунде работать не будет.

Comment: есть радар еще с xcode6 http://www.openradar.me/17731602

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, в случаях разработки консольной программы нужно запускать проект, выбрав **Command Line Tool**, где `readline()` будет работать и обрабатывать входные значения.